# Correlation with adjustment

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, weighted-regression, adjustment

I have data from several animals that are tested daily for 15 days on the presence of seizures. I have the latency of the seizures(when it begins after the start of experiment) and they occur on some days and not others. I wanted to correlate the latency with number of days using all data from all animals. However, some animals have seizures on day 6, some day 14 etc. How can I properly adjust for this if I want to measure a correlation between the number of days and seizure latency over days.